# Starting an external Java program from a Java program

Tags: java, process

This question has been asked before but with no real answer.

I wan't to start a Java Progam form another Java Program.
In my case I wan't to start the same program(2) and then exit the original program(1) while the clone is still open.

Unfortunatly I can't get this to work with ProcessBuilder

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("java","Programm");

Process process = processBuilder.start();
```

No error message, nothing happens.

I also can't run the program from the CMD in windows.
`javac` shows several errors during compilation:

> symbol not found, ...

I can start the program normally from Eclipse.

Comment: `symbol not found` maybe you forgot to set classpath? Especially when it works with eclipse. Also, it would help if you could provide more information and the concrete call of your `ProcessBuilder`

Comment: If you run javac to compile it, you need to add all needed jars to the classpath. See the javadoc for javac. (javac -classpath ...)

Comment: *"I wan't to start the same program(2) and then exit the original program"*  Why, what are you trying to achieve by doing that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably aren't seeing the errors from your `Process` because they are sent to its own error stream. You can access the error stream using `process.getErrorStream()`.

I suspect the problem is that your classpath isn't properly set when invoking the `java` executable and it is failing to find your class or its dependencies, but it is hard to tell without seeing the error.